# Export number in tsv from oracle with decimal separator (comma)

Tags: python, oracle, csv, export-to-csv, separator

I am loading data to tsv using the module of python:

```
cursor = con.cursor()
tsv_file = open(f"{name}.tsv", "w",encoding='UTF-8')
csv.writer(tsv_file, delimiter='\t',quotechar="", lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
r = cursor.execute(f"""select column1, column2, or_num
 from tablename s
""")
writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

There is a column in Oracle:                                                   [image: Data in column] 
But in the downloaded file, the numbers contain a dot
[image: number from file]

I tried:
1) `to_char(round(or_num),'9999D999')or_num` 
 Result- regular numbers with spaces at the beginning and extra zeros after the separator: [image: 16,000] 
2) `to_char(or_num,'9990D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')` 
Result - like first example 
3) `replace(or_num,'.',',')`
 Result:   ,8  need 0,8 
I want to get this result (change dot to comma) [image: result]

Comment: rtrim(to_char(or_num,'FM9999999D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''),',')

Answer (score 0):

To set the decimal character to a comma and the grouping separator to a period, 
specify the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` parameter at session level as follows:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ",."
```

Now in same session, execute your query to see the result in downloaded csv file.

Cheers!!

Comment: If you unload from PL \ sql developer then yes, it will unload with a comma, but I don’t understand what part of the code I need to insert into script

Comment: You need to find the way of executing query mentioned in the answer in your python code